# Sorting Product by Order rating with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'am trying so sort some Products by some attributes. E.g. the price is not the problem but the rating is.

Each product can have many orders and each order has a feedback including the rating.

1. Product 1

   - Order 1
     rating: 3
   - Order 2
     rating: 2
2. Product 2

   - Order 1
     rating: 3
3. Product 3

On the Product Model is use this function to get the rating

```
$feedBacks = Order::where([
  'product_id' => $this->id
])->has('feedBack')->get()->load('feedBack')->lists('feedBack');
if ($feedBacks->count() == 0)
  $rating = 0;
else
  $rating = floor($feedBacks->sum('rating') / $feedBacks->count());
```

But I need this function for a database query. I wasn't able to find a solution yet, maybe you can help me.

**Update:**

I think the structure is not so good.
The Model Product has many Orders,
so one Order belongs to one Product.
A Feedback has One Order,
so one Order belongs to one Feedback.

Everything is pointing to the Order, so I can get a product with all orders all Feedbacks with their orders.

So my solution would be to say that an order has one feedback and a feedback belongs to an order. With this straight format it should be possible to get the result.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you may want to consider keeping a product rating field in your products table and updating it with the new average whenever new feedback is posted.

Comment: This would be the lazy solution. But I think it's better style to do it by a query because then you don't have to worry if an order is deleted.

Comment: What models and relations have you defined?

Comment: A Product has many Orders. A Order has one feedback

Comment: I agree, make an order have one feedback and a feedback belong to an order.

Comment: I think have a query for you, but still I'm not sure how that should work. If there can be multiple products on an order, but order has a single feedback, then the feedback will rate the order, not the products, right? I mean, users are rating the quality of ther order?

Comment: Each order contains just one product, sorry for this missing information. I created an extra varibale for products including the rating which will be updated for every rating. So I don't have to caltucalte the rating every time.